# Can I be Terminated For Not Getting the Required Approvals from my Manager?

Tags: united-states, termination

I recently was put on a PIP for not receiving quaternary approval on a small data change. While I had not received approval from my direct manager, I had received approval from the owner, VP and a senior auditor. My manager stated that he was monitoring the data daily for years, but the event had occurred 8 months prior.

The HR manager agreed with my direct manager that I should be gaining approval directly from my manager even when others have already spoken to him about the task. Within the PIP, it states that I need approval from my manager for training.

On my most recent training a VP had a meeting with my manager and received approval from my manager to have me host the training. The training was critical and to be held the following day. I reached out to my manager, but did not receive a response. I have an email from the VP stating that my direct manager approved the training, however, I never received a response from my boss.

**Is this grounds for termination since the VP received approval from my direct manager, but not an identical request approval from me?  How can I work around this? Should I start looking for other jobs?**

Comment: As I read this, you probably should have started looking for another job the moment they first handed you the PIP.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I sent over a request to my manager, but he did not respond.  My manager does not typically respond to me via email. I had 38 attendees for a training the VP already sent out, so I wasn't sure what to do.  It is a common occurrence for me to not hear anything from my manager but be assigned to tasks and trainings.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Yep, definitely in the market, but my current package is really difficult to match.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere This is US based. I'll update with a tag.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Maybe I need to update the question. My manager rarely responds to my communications. I'm still waiting on approval after several follow ups for a critical request that's three weeks old. We've not met on this since we had the HR manager on the line.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, or as I like to say, you can be terminated if your socks are untied.

Comment: Contact the VP and tell him that you have not heard back from the manager and that, per your PIP, you may not continue until you hear from him directly, and see what he says.

Comment: @RichardU The training already occurred because the VP told me it was critical.  I still have not heard back from my manager on the original request and it's been over a week. They've asked me to do another training and I reached out again to my manager on this. I just received an email asking "What training are you referring to?". I provided the email that has the VP gaining approval from my direct manager. He sent a read receipt, but did not respond.  I'll reach out to the VP to get his take on this.

Comment: You have a dysfunctional management chain.  Get out.  Get out now.  Don't look back.

Comment: Just as an aside...anytime you type "I was put on a PIP" should have somewhere in there saying "and while I'm looking for a new job".  A PIP is like HR, it's not there to benefit you, it's to benefit the company, i.e. give them cover to terminate you with less repercussions. In my experience, "PIP" means "we're planning on firing you but we want to make it look better for us so you can't even get unemployment."

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted?  Is this not on topic?

Comment: Hazy as Richard say you can be fire for almost anything. So the answer for that is short. If you want to know how handle a manager who doesn't communicate that is a different issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this grounds for termination since the VP received approval from my
>   direct manager, but not an identical request approval from me?

Yes it is. In the US pretty much everything can be constructed as a grounds for termination. Regardless if it's reasonable or not.

> How can I work around this?

Over-communicate. Copy HR, the VP and your manager on every communication. Add a sentence "in case I don't hear back from you in time I will do XXX. Please let me know immediately if you want me to do something else"

> Should I start looking for other jobs?

Yes, absolutely. A PIP is more often than not a means of last resort and the final step before termination. All things that could have realistically work should be tried BEFORE you start the PIP. The PIP is primarily a legal defense measure: the company shows due diligence which reduces legal exposure risk. It also feels like a very artificial complaint. It's quite possible that the decision has already been made and the rest is just for show.

Comment: yes, I agree, especially the last paragraph

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things going on here.

1. Yes you should always follow your direct manager's direction as he is ultimately responsible for you.  If you go around him you step on toes and cause triangulation.
2. Yes the owner/VP is the boss, but it should not overwrite #1
3. Bosses should communicate with each other, which apparently isn't happening here as there is obviously some mixed message communication going on and even triangulation between the VP and your manager.

I have always found that over-informing is much less offensive than under-informing.  I would send all communication to your manager and also to whoever else you are talking with.  This will ensure that everyone is getting the same message from you.  If you are on a PIP for not following your manager, then adhere to his plan and if a time crunch is there respond to all saying that you need official approval from your manager to you in order to do this according to the [list specific agreement text here] and you are waiting on that confirmation in order to proceed as instructed.  CC everyone involved so they all know you are being really sure to communicate.

If the above is offensive to someone, at least the blame is in the right place now.  If you don't do this you will take the fall for your manager as there seems to be a power struggle in the management ranks.  The best approach is to make yourself compliant to all rules and very communicative about trying to comply to everyone you work for.  Let them fight it out and you adhere strictly to the direction of your boss.

P.S. If the nature of the management is hostile I would certainly be putting feelers out for other jobs as a safety backup in case things go south.  Firing can be justified in tons of ways even if not totally legit, so if someone wants you gone you will be.  However, a PIP also shows a possible desire to train you even if it is a little harsh, so I wouldn't make a conclusion yet, but just try to be ready for either direction.